# How to hide the name of a page from a list if it has no child sub pages in sightly?

Tags: aem, sightly

I want to display only those pages in the header which have child pages inside them. Using the following code

```html
<nav class="wsmenu clearfix" data-sly-use.nav="in.gov.odishatourism.core.models.HeaderNavigation">
<ul class="wsmenu-list"  >
    <li aria-haspopup="true"  data-sly-repeat="${nav.root.listChildren}" ><span class="wsmenu-click" ><i class="wsmenu-arrow fa fa-angle-down"></i></span>
        <a class="" href="javascript:void(0);" data-sly-test="!${item.hasChild}">${item.title}</a>
        <div class="wsmegamenu clearfix ">
            <div class="container paddingmenu">
                 <div class="row">
                     <div class="menuimgdiv"  data-sly-repeat.subcategory="${item.listChildren}">
                         <h3 class="title" data-sly-test.subcat="${subcategory.title}" >${subcat}</h3>
                         <ul>
                             <li data-sly-repeat.page="${subcategory.listChildren}"><a class="" href="${page.path  @ extension='html'}">${page.title}</a></li>
                         </ul>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </li>
     <li aria-haspopup="true"><a href="http://dot.odishatourism.gov.in/" target="_blank"> Dept of Tourism</a></li>
</ul>
<a class="wsdownmenu-animated-arrow"><span></span></a>
<div class="wsdownmenu-text">Navigation</div>
</nav>
```

gives the following output

[image]

But this code -

```html
<nav class="wsmenu clearfix" data-sly-use.nav="in.gov.odishatourism.core.models.HeaderNavigation">
    <ul class="wsmenu-list"  >
        <li aria-haspopup="true"  data-sly-repeat="${nav.root.listChildren}" ><span class="wsmenu-click" ><i class="wsmenu-arrow fa fa-angle-down"></i></span>
            <a class="" href="javascript:void(0);" data-sly-test="${item.hasChild}">${item.title}</a>
                <div class="wsmegamenu clearfix ">
                    <div class="container paddingmenu">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="menuimgdiv"  data-sly-repeat.subcategory="${item.listChildren}">
                                <h3 class="title" data-sly-test.subcat="${subcategory.title}" >${subcat}</h3>
                                <ul>
                                    <li data-sly-repeat.page="${subcategory.listChildren}"><a class="" href="${page.path  @ extension='html'}">${page.title}</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li aria-haspopup="true"><a href="http://dot.odishatourism.gov.in/" target="_blank"> Dept of Tourism</a></li>
        </ul>
        <a class="wsdownmenu-animated-arrow"><span></span></a>
        <div class="wsdownmenu-text">Navigation</div>
    </nav>
```

gives the output as shown below

[image]

The code

```html
<a class="" href="javascript:void(0);" data-sly-test="${item.hasChild}">${item.title}</a>
```

is not working properly.

My site structure is as shown below

[image]

And the actual desired output is

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `${item.hasChild}` in your test condition as the [hasChild()](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/javadoc/com/day/cq/wcm/api/Page.html#hasChild(java.lang.String)) method of the Page API requires you to pass a parameter. AFAIK, HTL doesn't support invocation of parameterized methods.

Since there is no direct API available to check if a page has child pages or not, you may need to do the following to validate if the page has child pages

```
<a class="" href="javascript:void(0);" data-sly-test="${item.listChildren && item.listChildren.hasNext}">${item.title}</a>
```

However, I would prefer building the entire navigation tree using Sling models or WCM Use API and not invoking so many methods in the HTL. That would make the code easier to maintain, change and test. YMMV